# Performing a segue on a view controller that is nested inside of another view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, segue, uicontainerview

I have a view controller which is nested inside of another view controller using a container view. Is it possible for me to segue from the view which is currently in the container view and replace it with another view controller in the same container view. I.e. the content that is around the container view is not removed by another view controller taking up the entire view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can read about that in the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1).

Considering your containerView currently only has one viewcontroller, here is a very basic example:

```
func loadVCWithId(idToLoad: String){
    childViewControllers[0].willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    childViewControllers[0].view.removeFromSuperview()
    childViewControllers[0].removeFromParentViewController()

    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(idToLoad)

    UIView.transitionWithView(yourContainer, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {self.yourContainer.addSubview((secondViewController?.view)!)}, completion: nil)


    secondViewController!.view.frame = firstContainer.bounds
    // do initialization of secondViewController here
    secondViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

`loadVCWithId(idToLoad:String)`is a method within your host viewcontroller.

In this code fragment I delete the current content of the container (probably not the best way to just access index 0, but for the sake of this example, this should be enough), instantiate a new ViewController by ID (this one is present in my storyboard but not accessbile yet), animate the transition and actually add the new VC to the container.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this my solution maybe helpful for

**first i create a protocol on childViewController**

```
protocol ChildViewControllerDelaget

{

    func performForSegue(SegueIdentifier:String)

}

class ChildViewController: UIViewController {

   var delaget:ChildViewControllerDelaget?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

   }

  init() 
    {  

     }


 @IBAction func myAction(sender: AnyObject) {

if delaget != nil {
deleget.performForSegue("mySegueIdentifier")
}

}
```

**and on MainViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,ChildViewControllerDelaget  {


    override func viewDidLoad()

    {

      super.viewDidLoad()

      let child = ChildViewController()

      child.delaget = self



    }

    func performForSegue(segueIdentifier:String) 

   {

      self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier, sender: nil)

    }

}
```